# validation not working in bootstrap data modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

Validation not working.I am using bootstrap Modal to show the users input form and has a confirmation button.I have submitted the first form which calls the validation and modal at the same time.

```
<form class="form-phone" name="frm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add_name" action="">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ex_model" name="ex_model" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ex_serial" name="ex_serial" required>                              
    <button style="width:100% ; margin-top:15px; border-radius:0; font-weight:bold;" type="button"  id="subBtn" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"  >GET OFFER</button>                   
</form>
```

Here is the script

```
<script >   
   $(document).ready(function(){  
        $('#subBtn').click(function() {             
            $("#add_name").validate({
                rules: {
                    ex_model: {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 8
                    },
                    ex_serial: "required"
                },
                messages: {
                    ex_model: {
                        required: "Please enter  modaldata",
                        minlength: "Your data must be at least 8 characters"
                    },      
                    ex_serial: "Please enter some data"
                }   
            });                 
        });   
    });
</script>
```

Comment: First of all i would advice you to place your scripts at the bottom of the <html> so just before </html>. Also check the `console` from chrome or another browser (the one you're using to check if all scripts are loaded correctly in the right order. Secondly i'm not seeing any bootstrap inclusion, though it could be that you just didn't add it to the snippet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to validate this form on submit button click event instead of you can validate that form on `$(document).ready(function(){})` itself

```js
$(function(){
    $("#add_name").validate({
        rules: {
            ex_model: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 8
            },
            ex_serial: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            ex_model: {
                required: "Please enter  modaldata",
                minlength: "Your data must be at least 8 characters"
            },      
            ex_serial: "Please enter some data"
        }
    })

    $("#subBtn").on("click", function(){
        if($("#add_name").valid()){
            //alert("success");
            $("#myModal").modal("show");
        } else {
            //alert("Values are not entered");
            //whatever you want to do when values are not entered
        }
        return false;
    });
})
```

```html
<link rel='stylesheet' href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/additional-methods.min.js"></script>

<form class="form-phone" name="frm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="add_name" action="">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ex_model" name="ex_model" required>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ex_serial" name="ex_serial" required>                              
        <button style="width:100% ; margin-top:15px; border-radius:0; font-weight:bold;" type="button"  id="subBtn" class="btn btn-success" >GET OFFER</button>                   
</form>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
       <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-body">
           <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
       </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
           <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for your support. But i need to validate the form by using type="button" not submit. Is it possible?.

Comment: what does it matter your form will not be submitted

Comment: i have update my code with button instead of submit please check now

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can validate form using below code

```
$("subBtn").on('click', function() {
   $("#add_name").valid();
});
```